# Random list element, multiple calls

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to randomise the background colour of ten containers. Using the current jQuery, the colour is randomised on load however the same colour is used for all of the containers. How would I alter the code to call separately for each instance of `.box`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var colors = ["#BF2642","#191B29","#366377"];                
  var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length);           
  $('.box').css("background-color", colors[rand]);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just loop over the `.box` elements and compute `rand` for each one:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var colors = ["#BF2642","#191B29","#366377"];                
  $('.box').each(function(){
      var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length);           
      $(this).css("background-color", colors[rand]);
  });
});
```